# Can't figure out keyerror in python code from Udacity CS101

Tags: python

I am currently going through the cs101 course on Udacity and I am getting an error

```
Keyerror 'a'
```

I don't see where that is coming from. I understand you can get key errors if you are searching for a key that doesn't exist.

This code is supposed to search through a dictionary of classes and print out the semesters and classes that a person is involved in, regardless of if they are teacher or assistant. Also, there is not always an assistant.

for if someone teaches cs101 in sprg15  it would look like this
`{"sprg1d":["cs101"]}`

```
courses = {
    'feb2012': { 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine',
                           'teacher': 'Dave',
                           'assistant': 'Peter C.'},
                 'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car',
                           'teacher': 'Sebastian',
                           'assistant': 'Andy'}},
    'apr2012': { 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine',
                           'teacher': 'Dave',
                           'assistant': 'Sarah'},
                 'cs212': {'name': 'The Design of Computer Programs',
                           'teacher': 'Peter N.',
                           'assistant': 'Andy',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs253': 
                {'name': 'Web Application Engineering - Building a Blog',
                           'teacher': 'Steve',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs262': 
                {'name': 'Programming Languages - Building a Web Browser',
                           'teacher': 'Wes',
                           'assistant': 'Peter C.',
                           'prereq': 'cs101'},
                 'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car',
                           'teacher': 'Sebastian'},
                 'cs387': {'name': 'Applied Cryptography',
                           'teacher': 'Dave'}},
    'jan2044': { 'cs001': {'name': 'Building a Quantum Holodeck',
                           'teacher': 'Dorina'},
               'cs003': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Robotics Teacher',
                           'teacher': 'Jasper'},
                     }
    }

def involved(courses, person):
    inv={}
    for term in courses:
        for c in term:
            for i in courses[term][c]:                
                if courses[term][c][i]==person:
                    if term in inv:
                        inv[term].append(c)
                    else:
                        inv[term]=[c]
    return inv
```

Comment: Python should have given you a traceback. It looks like this: "Traceback (most recent call last)..." Please add it to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for term in courses` loop yields *keys*; these are strings here. So `term` is first assigned one of the keys in `['apr2012', 'jan2044', 'feb2012']`.

The next loop loops over the characters in `term` then:

```
for term in courses:
    for c in term:
```

if `term` is set to `apr2012`, `c` is set to `a` first. There is no `courses['apr2012']['a']` entry however.

You probably wanted to loop over the associated values instead:

```
for term in courses:
    for c in courses[term]:
```

You could build the result with a list comprehension nested in a dictionary comprehension:

```
def involved(courses, person):
    return {t: [cn for cn, v in c.iteritems() if person in v.itervalues()]
            for t, c in courses.iteritems()}
```

albeit that this can return empty lists. If that's a problem, simplify your code to:

```
def involved(courses, person):
    inv = {}
    for term, course in courses.iteritems():
        for course_name, info in course.iteritems():
            if person in info.itervalues():
                inv.setdefault(term, []).append(course_name)
    return inv
```

For Python 3, remove all `iter` prefixes.

Comment: I swear I thought I fixed that.. maybe I was just staring at it too much.